# How to use getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i getting error while using getElementByClassName.
My intension is that i want to change the color of multiple TEXT over the selection of an option from drop down list where each option is having different color.

Here i have assigned a single className to all text.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function copyText(selectedElement) {
            var className = document.getElementsByClassName("incomeTypeSalary");
            for (i = 0; i < className.length; i++)

            {
               className[i].style.color = selectedElement.options[selectedElement.selectedIndex].style.color;
            }

         }
      </script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <div style="width:600px;border:1px solid black;float:left">
         <select width="200px" id="selectedElement" onclick="copyText(selectedElement)">
            <option style="color:red">Theta Saving Plan</option>
            <option style="color:green">Roth Plan</option>
            <option style="color:yellow">IRG Plan</option>
            <option style="color:PINK">II Plan</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div style="width:300px;border:1px solid black;float:left">
         <span style="padding-top:30px;font-size:24px;font-family:arial:" class="incomeTypeSalary">Contribution</span>
         <table style="padding-top:24px">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <span class="incomeTypeSalary">Annual Salary</span>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" style="width:81px; direction:rtl;">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <span class="incomeTypeSalary2">Annual Coomission</span>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" style="width:81px; direction:rtl;">
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <span class="incomeTypeSalary3">Annual Bonus</span>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type="text" style="width:81px; direction:rtl;">
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

PLs help me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please paste your error scenario

Comment: Title: `getElementByClassName` --> `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 1):

Change the `onclick` to `onchange`

http://jsfiddle.net/wQWdg/

---

this will work for all the browsers

```
function getElementsByClassName(className) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
        return document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    }
    else {
        return document.querySelectorAll('.' + className);
    }
}​
```

Comment: hey thanks i tried what u said....bt its still nt working ..color is not reflecting back to text

Comment: check the link for working sample

Comment: hey sorry to say but i have tried the above link in IE8 and firefox but its not working..

Comment: changing `copyText(selectedElement)` to `copyText(this)` will work for firefox and chrome. IE has a known issue with this. for all browser support use jQuery `$('.incomeTypeSalary')`

Comment: thanks its working now....but can u suggest me some bettr idea than this to change the color of multiple text on option selection...

Comment: if you unable to move to jQuery solution, try [this working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/wQWdg/4/)